# C++ HANDLE пауза процесса

Tags: c++

У меня есть HANDLE чужого процесса, как мне поставить паузу этому процессу и потом продолжить его? P.S. ос windows.

Answer (score 1):

Процесс на паузу поставить нельзя. На паузу можно поставить поток, заморозить его, так сказать. Как известно, процесс без единого потока, что яблоня без гусеницы. Пользы от такого процесса нет никакой и система Windows автоматически удаляет его, а точнее виндовый сборщик мусора( что на уровне системы ). Всем известно, что основополагающая любого процесса - это его главный поток, который управляет всеми потоками, созданными в `REALTIME MODE` если таковые есть, конечно же. Так вот и "заморозьте" главный поток, используя стандартные виндовые функции: [**SuspendThread / ResumeThread**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Сам процесс как бы создаст иллюзию "стопа", на самом же деле замороженным будет его главный поток.

Comment: На самом деле не стоит зацикливаться на глагне потоке, тем более, что у всяких фреймворков главный поток это UI. Логичнее было бы заснуть всё потоки процесса.

Comment: А если потоков, скажем 50 ? Это же как-то "в лоб".

Comment: @Dexter

- В лоб тут скорее то, что заморозка средствами `WinAPI` **одного** из тредов чужого приложения при наличии других тредов - это нехилый шаг в сторону `undefined behavior`. Откуда можно знать, что такое вмешательство в чужой процесс не приведет к его `crash'у` или рассинхронизации?

- Именно по этой причине есть способ *атомарно* `заsuspend'ить` процесс - `NtSuspendProcess`.

- Не знаю, как работает перловый [`Win32::Process::Suspend,`][1] но, возможно, есть смысл глянуть его сорцы.

[1]: http://search.cpan.org/~rootkwok/Win32-Process-Suspend-0.0642/lib/Win32/Process/Suspend.pm